# Finding and replacing words with asterisk, in a text file output

Tags: haskell

Hello I am new at Haskell and i'm having problems trying to get this script to work. This script reads in arguements from a command line and find them in a seperate text file.

E.G: cat.txt | ./redact house big cat (in compiler)

It redacts certain words in a text file by replacing them with stars (**)asterisks. The number of stars used for each redacted word should equal the number of characters in the word.

```
module Main where

import System
import Data.Char
import Data.List

lowercase :: String -> String
lowercase = map toLower

main = do 
arg1 <- getArgs
txt <- getContents
putStr (redact txt arg1)

redact :: String -> String -> String
redact input xWords = unlines [ work line | line <- lines input ]
where work line = unwords [ foo word | word <- words line ]
  foo w | lowercase(w) == lowercase(xWords) = convertWord w 1
    | otherwise                         = w

convertWord Eq a => [a] -> [a]
convertWord = map (const '*')
```

However, when i try to compile this, GHCi returns the error:

```
redact.hs:13:38:
    Couldn't match expected thye 'Char' with actual type '[Char]'
    Expected type: String
     Actual type: [String]
    In the second argument of 'redact', namely 'arg1'
    In the first of 'putStr', namely '<redact txt arg1>'
Failed, module loaded: none.
```

So the code:

```
putStr (redact txt arg1)
```

is causing the problem.

Thank you in advance for any help and if you can improve the code in anyway that would be great.

**EDIT:**

I want to enter as many args as possible, it doesnt matter how many args you enter, i tried:

```
(arg1:arg2:arg3:arg4:arg5:_) <- getArgs
```

but I have to enter EXACT  5 args, It shouldn't matter how many args I enter.
I was thinking of using some kind of loop but I am not sure?

Again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to work with multiple arguments, use `getArgs` as you have it. The problem lies with

```
foo w | lowercase(w) == lowercase(xWords) = convertWord w 1
      | otherwise                         = w
```

where you compare the lowercase of one word to lowercase of multiple words. The latter is not defined, you'd like to compare it to the lowercase of *each* of the `xWords`. So first you need to bring them all to lowercase, that's most efficiently done by calling from main `redact txt (map lowercase arg1)` rather than just `redact txt arg1`. Then you need to determine if a read word is *in* the list `xWords`, that's what the `elem` function is there for.

```
foo w | lowercase w `elem` xWords = convertWord w 1
      | otherwise                 = w
```

BTW, you should maybe not call this function `foo` even if it's only a local one.

Answer (score 1):

`getArgs :: IO [String]`, so after `arg1 <- getArgs`, `arg1` has the type `[String]`: it contains *all* the arguments passed to your program, as a list. But you're using it as `String`, thus the error: GHC expected `arg1` to be a `String`, but it's a `[String]`.

You can pattern-match on the result like this:

```
arg1:_ <- getArgs
```

This results in `arg1` containing the first element of the list, and discards the rest of the list. If you don't pass an argument, it'll result in a runtime error. Of course, if you want more specialised behaviour (say, printing an error when no arguments are given), you could use a more complex method of extracting the first argument, such as a `case` expression.

As far as improvements to your program go:

- You can simplify the definition of `work` using function composition and `map` rather than the list comprehension: `work = unwords . map foo . words` (read: "map `foo` over all the elements of the `words`, then `unwords` them").
- `redact` can be simplified similarly, to `redact input xWords = unlines . map work . lines $ input`.
- `lowercase(w)` is better written as `lowercase w`.

But your program looks basically fine to me, apart from some oddities (like the missing `::` in `convertWord`'s type signature, the additional `1` you pass to it in `foo` — but going by the somewhat erratic indentation, I guess you edited the code before posting it). I wouldn't make the first two changes unless you understand how they work and are comfortable writing code like that.

Comment: According to the example, using _all_ arguments was what the OP actually wanted.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Hmm, right. I was fooled by the naming of `arg1`. Oh well, hopefully the rest of my advice is helpful...